# Examining Multiple Elements to Determine Their Color Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a basic productivity schedule, and I need a way to set the color of the different time blocks to gray, red, or green depending on if they are in the past, present, or future. For example, if we are presently in the 5 o'clock hour, that time block with the scheduled event text would need to be red.

The following code is what I've tried but I'm not able to get it to work

HTML - using bootstrap. I have 8 of these rows, one for each of the hours in the work day (9-5). Take note of the data-time attribute. It is set to whatever hour it represents.

```
      <div class = "row" data-time = "9">
        <div class = "col-md-3">
          <p>0900</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-6">
          <textarea class = "event-field"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button></div>
      </div>
```

```
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours();

$(document).ready(function() {
    var rows = $("div.row")
    var dataAttString = rows.dataset.time;
    var dataAttNum = Number(dataAttString);    

    if (dataAttNum < time) {
        rows.addClass("past");
    }
    else if (dataAttNum === time) {
        rows.addClass("present");
    }
    else if (dataAttNum > time) {
        rows.addClass("future");
    }
    });
```

Comment: can you share what your HTML looks like? It'd be a lot faster that way :)

Comment: Sure! Just edited in the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mixing jQuery and Vanilla JS, I coded everything in jQuery.

The main issue is that `.rows` is an array of `div`s - i.e.

```
var rows = $("div.row")
```

So, you need to iterate through each element in the array to determine its value and change its bg-color according to the `data-time` attribute.

**See demo below**

```js
// getting current hours from timestamp;
var date = new Date();
var time = date.getHours();

// once document is loaded and ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = $("div.row")

  // rows is an array of divs, let's work with each element one by one 
  $.each(rows, function(idx, row) {
    //remove previous classes assigned to it (this may not be necessary)
    $(row).removeClass("past");
    $(row).removeClass("present");
    $(row).removeClass("future");

    // Read the value of the data-time attribute & turn it into a number
    var dataAttString = $(row).data('time');
    var dataAttNum = Number(dataAttString);

    // assign a CSS class according to the current hour (calculated at the beginning)
    if (dataAttNum < time) {
      $(row).addClass("past");
    } else if (dataAttNum === time) {
      $(row).addClass("present");
    } else if (dataAttNum > time) {
      $(row).addClass("future");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* CSS Classes */
.past {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.present {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.future {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" data-time="0000">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>0001</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea class="event-field"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button></div>

  <div class="row" data-time="12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>0900</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <textarea class="event-field"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></button></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is now working. It'll take me some time to dissect exactly what you've done. For instance, I'm not familiar with the use of  idx, but I can take it and investigate from here.

Comment: @KarrenAD I can add better comments on the code tomorrow... I’m done for the day ;) - cheers

Comment: @KarrenAD I added some comments on the code, I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getHours();
    var rows = $("div.row")

rows.each(function(){
    var dataAttNum = $(this).data('time');    

    if (dataAttNum < time) {
        $(this).addClass("past");
    }
    else if (dataAttNum === time) {
        $(this).addClass("present");
    }
    else if (dataAttNum > time) {
        $(this).addClass("future");
    }

})
    });
```